# Texture rendering issue when scaling with a matrix

Tags: c#, .net, xna, rendering, monogame

I am working on a game (in XNA/MonoGame) in which I have large world consisting of many individual tiles with different textures. I store my world as a 2D array and to render it, I simply loop through every tile and draw it at the correct position.

Recently I implemented a zoom feature in my camera. My game's camera is made in the 'usual' XNA way where you have create a matrix based on position and scale and that pass that into your SpriteBatch.Begin() calls. My transform matrix is calculated as so:

`Transform = Matrix.Identity *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(-(int)Position.X, -(int)Position.Y, 0) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(Origin.X, Origin.Y, 0) *
    Matrix.CreateScale(Scale);`

The problem I am now facing is when I zoom in (by changing the camera's scale variable) some tile textures look odd at some zoom levels. Here are some pictures showing what I mean:

Here is a map at perfectly fine zoom level:
[image]

Here is a zoomed out (and cropped) view of the same map, notice how the sand texture is wierdly "upscaled":

[image]

I do not have much experience with graphics programming and really have no idea what this is caused by, but it makes the map look very janky.

Comment: Have you applied camera matrix to the file object matrix?

Comment: Hmm, it's almost like your zooming in on the sand textures... could you provide the code you're using to draw the tiles?